# Are there any Webtoon manga that are in black-and-white?

Tags: manga-production

Are there any manga on [Webtoon](https://www.webtoons.com/en/) that are in black-and-white? I couldn't find a single one that's in black-and-white, all of them use colors, but I would like to know if you know some examples that have black-and-white panels so I can look at how they're formatted and how different they are from those with colors.

I'm asking because someone told me that it's now a requirement on the platform for series to be in color, but I couldn't find the rule specifically anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

[This article](https://www.webtoons.com/en/creators101/webtoon-canvas/canvas-news/16) published by the Webtoon staff lists ten series that are published on the site in black-and-white. It would indeed appear that being in full colour is not a requirement to being published on Webtoon.